# send mail() php xampp yahoo

Tags: php, email, xampp

Can anyone help me? 
I am stuck with PHP `mail()` function, I have already set `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini`. I'm just using function `mail($to,$subject,$content)` and didn't work. I'm using localhost XAMPP.

This the `php.ini` file:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.mail.yahoo.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = jesus4way@yahoo.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\apache\logs\php_mail.log"
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Check the return value of `mail()` to see if the email was accepted for delivery. If `true` it's probably a spam filter blocking the mail, if `false` it's probably server config.

Comment: You use `localhost XAMPP`. Did you install any [SMTP server](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercwin.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

**Check server status**

- Start Mercury Mail Server from XAMPP Control Panel. Check if status is `Running`.
- Open Mercury control panel (from XAMPP Panel or taskbar) and check if SMTP server status is `Ready`.
- Send mail message to your own e-mail address from Mercury control panel and check if it fails or not.

**PHP**

Allow error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check for PHP errors and warnings.

Try to add header info to your `mail()` function:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: I have sent a test email using murcury, its fine but when I wrote php code and test it its not work for me

Comment: I am not getting any error, however i have configured it with gmail now and it is working fine :)